# Java loop with same method but with different system.out

Tags: java

I am taking an Java Introduction class and we have a project that deals with a hangman game. I have most of the all code worked out but there is a way to simplify the code.

In my code below, the program will output a message for every round (max 3 round) then using `game.nextRound()` it set will a word using variable named `word1`, `word2`, `word3`. This variable will be called in sequence in descending order.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String word1 = "ruby";
        String word2 = "python";
        String word3 = "swift";

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        Hangman game = new Hangman();

        System.out.println("Let's play a round of hangman.");
        System.out.println("We are playing hangman");

        game.nextRound(word1);

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("The disguised word is " + game.disguised());
            System.out.println("Guess a letter:");
            char guess = kb.next().charAt(0);
            boolean isFound = game.guessLetter(guess);
            if (isFound) {
                game.result();
                if (game.disguised().equals(game.secret())) {
                    game.found();
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                game.result();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Let's play a second round of hangman.");
        System.out.println("We are playing hangman");

        game.nextRound(word2);

        ....
        ....
        ....
```

**Hangman.java**

```
public String disguised() {
    return disguisedWord;
}
```

Comment: your problem is ?

Comment: @JohnJoe i would like simplify the code if it is even possible as the while-loop is the same after every calling of game.nextRound()

Comment: @JohnJoe it have edited my main question see `Hangman.java` section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ArrayList`, and also use `counter` to indicate the number of the game.

```
public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int count = 1;

        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        words.add("ruby");
        words.add("python");
        words.add("swift");

        for (String word : words) {

            System.out.println("Let's play a round of " + count + "hangman.");
            System.out.println("We are playing hangman");

            Hangman game = new Hangman();

            game.nextRound(word);

            while (true) {
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("The disguised word is " + game.disguised());
                System.out.println("Guess a letter:");
                char guess = kb.next().charAt(0);
                boolean isFound = game.guessLetter(guess);
                if (isFound) {
                    game.result();
                    if (game.disguised().equals(game.secret())) {
                        game.found();
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    game.result();
                }
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following :

-Put the Strings `word1`, `word2`, and `word3` in an array of type String.
   Let's say

`String[] words = {"ruby", "python", "swift"};`

-Initialize an `int` counter set to 0.

```
int c = 0;
```

-Add `game.nextRound(words[c++]);` inside your if and else statements in the while     loop.

Comment: is it possible to do without arrays? sorry for not mentioning as my lecturer said arrays are reserved for project 2.

Comment: you can keep this counter and increment it by 1 each time you win or lose, then put 3 if statements at the start of your while loop and call the method with the right parameter depending on the counter c (round number)